# Common way to describe golang concurrency design?

Tags: go, design-patterns, concurrency

Go has a powerful concurrency support. With goroutines and channels, the synchronization is implemented in a different way than mutex.

Example: [Codewalk: Share Memory By Communicating](https://golang.google.cn/doc/codewalk/sharemem/)

However, when comes to describing the design, it seems not quite clear and easy since there may be many goroutines and channels involved, orchestrated.

Does anybody know if there's some common language/format in text or in diagram, to describe such design? (e.g. use above link as example)

Comment: It's not clear what you are after (and I think that Go's channels may well be implemented using mutexes internally - you are confusing different levels of abstraction here). The overall design was heavily influenced by CSP I believe though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes

Comment: There should not be much to explain about this program, except that it does not deal properly with its `main` exit condition. The code should suffice to itself for a reader to understand.

Comment: @mh-cbon, it's needed in design document.